# How to enable date formatting during edit while still applying crispy forms at the same time

Tags: python, django

On displaying edit form, date field format is YYYY-MM-DD yet I would like it to display in form of MM/DD/YYYY since am using the bootstrap date picker which I have configured to MM/DD/YYYY.

I tried rendering the date using the django defined date filters along side the crispy forms in this way

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="post" novalidate>
  <div>
   {{ form.start_date|date: "d M Y"}}    
  </div>
</form>
```

The output should be the new date in format MM/DD/YYYY though it says Could not parse the remainder: ': "d M Y"' from 'form.start_date|date: "d M Y"'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a single form field, you can specify the [**`input_formats=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats), and the [**`format=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateInput.format) of the widget:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateForm(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'),
        input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y']
    )
```

If you want to specify the format for all `DateField`s, you can specify the [**`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_INPUT_FORMATS):

```
# settings.py

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%m/%d/%Y',
    # ...
]
```